Keep a specific flexbox child from overflowing its container
I have the following layout:


.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.child {
  min-width: fit-content;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.first {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.second {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 1 1;
}
.third {
   background: blue;
   flex: 0 1 1;
}
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first child">first</div>
    <div class="container child second">
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third child">third</div>
  </div>
</div>



My problem is that, in the case of overflowing, i need to show a scroll on the second child alone, meaning the first and third child should always be visible, how can i do this?

Why don't flex items shrink past content size?

Also, you need to set overflow-x on the second child if you want it to overflow. The container also needs a max-width or width to limit the width to have overflow happen. Finally flex: 0 1 1 is syntactically invalid as far as I know.

You don't need most of the code you wrote. Keep it simple


.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container {
  display: flex; /* flexbox container */
}
.child {
  margin: 5px;
}
.first {
  background: yellow;
}
.second {
  background: red;
  flex: 1; /* fill remaining space */
  overflow: auto; /* add scrollbar if needed */
}
.third {
   background: blue;
}
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first child">first</div>
    <div class="container child second">
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third child">third</div>
  </div>
</div>



